# attempting to clear cookies of all the pages in a domain in a springboot application

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I am attempting to clear all the `cookies` in a domain using a logout function, the domain is this `localhost:8080`

When I attempt to clear the `cookie` from `dashboard` the `cookie` is cleared successfully. But when I navigate to `editprofile` from `dashboard` and attempt to clear cookie the cookie is not cleared as the cookie variable `{{user.username}}` is still shown on the index.

Here is my attempt:

```
$rootScope.logout = function() {
    delete $rootScope.user;
    $cookies.remove('token');
    //$location.path("/");
    $(location).attr('href', '/index');
    return;
};
```

here is what is defined in the index page

```
<a ng-show="user" class="item active" href="/dashboard">welcome {{user.username}}</a>
```

Comment: you need to clear `cookies` per `page`

Comment: okay, can u post a snippet

Comment: Note you can't clear `httpOnly` cookies set by server using javascript in page. They are protected and for good reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `cookies` you should use,

`$cookies.remove("cookieName")`

since yours is not a `single page application`, you should `remove` `cookies` from every page

`$cookies.remove(v, {path: '/yourpage'});`

In this way you can delete all `cookies`

```
var cookies = $cookies.getAll(); 
angular.forEach(Object.keys(cookies), function (v, k) { 
        $cookies.remove(v, {path: '/yourpage'}); 
});
```

**Code:**

```
$rootScope.logout = function() { 
    delete $rootScope.user; 
    var cookies = $cookies.getAll(); 
    angular.forEach(Object.keys(cookies), function (v, k) { 
        $cookies.remove(v, {path: '/index'}); 
        $cookies.remove(v, {path: '/editprofile'}); 
        $cookies.remove(v, {path: '/'}); 
    }); 

    $cookies.remove("token", {path: '/index'}); 
    $cookies.remove("token", {path: '/editprofile'}); 
    $cookies.remove("token", {path: '/'}); 
    $(location).attr('href', '/index'); 
    return; 
};
```